# K2: Call To A Member Function Get() On Null

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, menu-item

I want to create a page where visitors can submit an article from frontend in K2. But when I create a menu item with type as `item edit form` in K2, it throws an error in frontend. The whole website doesn't load.

> Call To A Member Function Get() On Null

I have also tried making the menu item only for registered users. But after login also, it gives the same error.

Comment: I would suggest posting this on the K2 forum as there isn't anything we can really do here at JSE

Comment: JSE gives quick response and therefore I posted here but sure will post there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted the issue on k2 forum and got the answer. Following is the issue's reason and solution:

1. In Helix Framework, when we create a menu item of type `item edit form`. It throws an error. So, this is the template issue. This option works fine in default joomla template.
2. If you want to allow users to submit article from frontend using a menu item, then in Helix, go to `Menu manager > menu item > set target window option to new window with navigation`. Only then it will work.
3. The best option is to use the login module of k2. When a user logs in, he can submit a new article by the option `post new item` in the user page or `add item` in the module.